# Cloud function is timing out as there are too many documents to update

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that runs as a cron job daily, that creates a daily stats doc for each of our users. The issue now is that with the amount of users we have, the function is timing out and therefore not creating the required document for each of our users.

The function is simply:

```
    export const createDailyStatsDocument = runWith({timeoutSeconds: 540}).https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    corsHandler(req, res, async () => {
        try {
            const users = await db.collection('users').get();
            for (const userDoc of users.docs) {
                 const data = {
                    uid: userDoc.uid,
                    test: 'test'
                }
                const statsRef = await createStatsDoc(data)
            }
            return res.status(200).send({message: 'Successfully created all users documents'});
        } catch (e) {
            console.log({e});
            return _handleError(res, e.status, e.message);
        }
    })
});
```

I have increased the function timeout to the maximum allowed by firestore, but still getting the same issue. Does anyone have a solution as to how to either increase the timeout of these functions, or to somehow trigger another function for each loop iteration that runs in a separate instance, so does not affect the timeout of this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do the trick. In the HTTPS Cloud Function, all the work is delegated to the PubSub Cloud Function (for each user a PubSub message is published). Once this is done, the HHTPS Cloud Function can be finished by sending the response.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const { PubSub } = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');  // <== See here!!
const pubSubClient = new PubSub();

admin.initializeApp();

// A function that will publish a Pub/Sub message
async function publishMessage(messageConfig) {
    try {

        const topicName = messageConfig.topicName;
        const pubSubPayload = messageConfig.pubSubPayload;

        let dataBuffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(pubSubPayload));
        await pubSubClient.topic(topicName).publish(dataBuffer);

    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}

// Your adapted Cloud Function
export const createDailyStatsDocument = runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 540 }).https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    corsHandler(req, res, async () => {
        try {
            const users = await db.collection('users').get();
            for (const userDoc of users.docs) {

                const messageConfig = {
                    topicName: 'daily-stats',
                    pubSubPayload: {
                        uid: userDoc.uid,
                        test: 'test'
                    }
                }
                await publishMessage(messageConfig);
            }
            return res.status(200).send({ message: 'Successfully created all PUBSub Messages' });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log({ e });
            return _handleError(res, e.status, e.message);
        }
    })
});


// The Pub/Sub Cloud Function that calculates the stat for each user
exports.calculateDailyStat = functions.pubsub.topic('daily-stats').onPublish(async (message) => {

    try {

        const data = {
            uid: message.json.uid,
            test: message.json.test
        }
        await createStatsDoc(data)

        return null;

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return null;
    }

});
```

---

Note that this code creates a Pub/Sub message for **each** user and therefore triggers the Pub/Sub Cloud Function for each user. If you want to group users in batches, it's up to you to adapt it. Just modify the `pubSubPayload` in order to pass an Array of data, and in the Pub/Sub Cloud Function loop over this array.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to extend the time a Cloud Function runs beyond its maximum value.

The typical solution for the problem you have is to divide the work into smaller chunks and let those run as separate tasks. For example, if you create chunks of up to 500 UIDs, and then post those to a PubSub topic, you can trigger another Cloud Function on that, and create those stats docs in a single batch write.

Comment: Could i post to the pubsub topic for each chunk within this one function asynchronously without this one timing out?

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea indeed. Your parent function would complete straight after its done reading and creating the chunks, while each chunk then runs in its own Cloud Function invocation.

Comment: and how would this look? Would it not need an await on each function call and therefore only end ones all have completed?

Comment: Nope, that's unlikely to help much. If you want a completion mechanism for all of them, you'll have to implement that on top. Like have the original function write the total count of tasks to be done, and then have each PubSub handler increment a counter of the work its done. Clients can listen to both and check for `completedCount == userCount`.

Comment: could you provide an example please? Don't think i quite understand what you mean